# C function to return concatenated string

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, concatenation

I am attempting to create a function in C to return a string that is the result of concatenating two smaller strings. My code looks like this:

```
const char *concat(char* s1, char* s2){
    char ns[strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1];
    ns[0] = '\0';
    strcpy(ns, s1);
    strcpy(ns, s2);
    return ns;
}
```

I understand that the string `ns` exists only within the scope of the function and cannot be returned, but a pointer string would not be editable and would defeat the purpose of the function. Is there a better way to do this or is the function fundamentally flawed?

Comment: *“but a pointer string would not be editable and would defeat the purpose of the function”* – what’s a pointer string? Using `char* ns = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);` would work fine. Also, you probably mean `strcat`, not `strcpy`, and may as well use `memcpy`.

Comment: You're absolutely right. The funny thing is that I was using `malloc` earlier and it was working, but I failed to recognize it.

Comment: Just make sure not to return a `const char*` in that case; `free` is used on non-`const` pointers.

Comment: replace     `strcpy(ns, s2);` with `strcat(ns, s2);`

Comment: In this case, because I want to edit the string in the function, would it best to make a non-static string and `free()` it later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this example, using strcat() is very simple way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void concat(char* s1, char* s2, char* ns) {
    ns[0] = '\0';
    strcpy(ns, s1);
    strcat(ns, s2);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char* s1="hola";
    char* s2 =" mundo";
    char s3[strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1];
    concat(s1, s2, s3);

    printf("\n%s",s3);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

find more info [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat)

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using `malloc()` to create a dynamic string in heap memory:

```
const char *concat(char* s1, char* s2){
    char *ns = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);
    ns[0] = '\0';
    strcat(ns, s1);
    strcat(ns, s2);
    return ns;
}
```

Make sure to `free()` the memory afterwards, though.

Answer (score 0):

The C function that concatenates two string is strcat!

```
int main(void)
{
    char *s1="Good ";
    char *s2="luck";

    char ns[12];

    strcpy(ns,s1);
    strcat(ns,s2);

    printf("%s\n",ns);

    return 0;
}
```

You may also use strcat in this way:

```
strcpy(ns,s1);
printf("%s\n", strcat(ns,s2));
```